# How to add item to cart by sku value called from custom attribute in bundle products?

Tags: php, jquery, html, magento, magento-1.9

I created a custom attribute 'Barebone SKU' and would like to add the product assigned to this SKU to cart by clicking on 'Buy Barebone Only' as shown on this page http://62.100.204.242/~beta3d/bundle-test.html

[image: back end image]

I'm not good at coding but here's what I've tried so far

```
<?php if ($_product->getTypeId() === 'bundle'):?>

<div class="add-to-cart-buttons" style="margin-bottom:10px; float:none;">
  <button type="button" title="Buy barebone only" style="padding:10px 0px;" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product->getBbsku) ?>')">Buy barebone/system only</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What does `setLocation` do?

Comment: I want it to add the product from custom attribute "Bbsku" value product SKU. However, its not adding anything to cart. In essence, I just want a button to add just the top bundle product to cart.